# Jquery - Coalition body border detection

Tags: jquery, menu, draggable

i have a problem with a draggable Menu.

**Example**
http://jsfiddle.net/55VJG/

It works finde but when i drag it to `right:0px;` or `buttom:0px;` my Menu is out of the browser.
How would you resolve this problem? Is it maybe possible to fix this only with css?

**HTML**

```
<div id="bar">
    Open
    <div id="menu"> Bookmarks <br /> Misc <br /> Some Stuff </div>  
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body { overflow:hidden; }
#bar { width: 100px; border: 1px solid #000; background-color:#ccc; top:0px; left:0px; position:fixed; }
#menu { display:none; border: 1px solid #f00; width:200px; height:200px; background-color:#555; }
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $('#bar').draggable();         

   $("#bar").hover( 
    function () { $('#menu').show(); },
    function () { $('#menu').hide(); });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the option `containment: 'document'` for it to not go outside the boundaries of your page. Also, the width of the element which triggers the menu should be the same with the width of your menu.

Here is a [**forked demo of yours**](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/dfFFm/).